# Add Links to pages From other Projects in solution explorer.

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have got this solution explorer.

[image]

WebApplication2 is my deafult project and i have got a default.aspx page. where i want to create links to pages in each project (WebApplication1, WebApplication3, WebApplication4). how do i create the links.

Comment: try adding reference of the project using "Add reference"

Comment: @KrunalPatil i did that but still can't create links